# How to set ALL of columns width in "Best fit" in VBA Access 2010

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I know for set the column width in best fit for a field with "Title" name the below code works:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Forms![Contacts]![Title].ColumnWidth = -2

End sub
```

is there any solution for ALL columns in datasheet view into one or two lines VBA Code?

Many Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim f As Object
Set f = Forms![Contacts]
' Or Set f = Me.Form

Dim c As Control
For Each c In f.Controls

    With c

        ' If textbox
        If .ControlType = acTextBox Then

            ' Adjust to best fit width
            .ColumnWidth = -2
        End If
    End With
Next c

Set c = Nothing
Set f = Nothing
```

Comment: Might I suggest you add some context to your code only answer?

Comment: Hum yes sure, but I'm not sure what context you mean. I think it's self explanatory considering the presented problem